# Open source alternatives to sales force

Tags: open-source, crm, sugarcrm

Is there any open source web application similar in features and operation to `salesforce.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are some forks of sugarcrm - like [vtiger](http://www.vtiger.com/).

Comment: Thanks a ton for you quick reply we looking for ERP and CRM at one place !!